# Brahmas and Devas?

Tags: rebirth, sutras, suttas, deva, brahma

Are Brahmas and Devas the same thing in different levels or are they two entirely different beings.

---

I am asking this because if see the first teaching of Lord Buddha (Dhamma chakka pawaththana) there is a mentioning "Brahma Deva",yes both words used as a combination.

Normally they are considered two kinds,here it is still the same but Brahmas have being attached to the Deva realm.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Buddhism, "Brahmā" is a type of deva.

(In Hinduism, [Brahmā](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahma) is the creator god, see also [Brahman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahman).)

Some online references to descriptions of the Buddhist "Brahmā" include:

- [Brahmā (Buddhism)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahm%C4%81_(Buddhism)) (Wikipedia)
- [The Glossary of Pali terms on the 'Buddha Vacana' web site](http://www.buddha-vacana.org/gloss.html#brahma):

  > **Brahmā:** is the supreme divinity of ancient brahmanism, considered as the creator of the universe and worshiped by brahmins through sacrifices and rituals. The Buddha gives this appellation to the *Brahmakāyika*, devas (etc.)
- Footnote 146 on page 51 of [the 'Dharma Farer' commentary on the Dhammacakkappavattana](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/1.1-Dhammacakka-Pavattana-S-s56.11-piya.pdf)

  > It is interesting and important to note that the list of exulting devas stops here with the Brahmās of the 1st dhyana.
  > The reason for this is that, as there is still some level of mentation here—by way of initial and sustained applications
  > (vitakka,vicāra)—these Brahmās are still in contact with the sense-world. In the realms beyond the 1st dhyana,
  > thought-process as we know it ceases completely so that these beings enjoy the glory of their meditative state as
  > pure light or profound peace for as long as their karma fuels it.

Answer (score 1):

@Theravada… as per the Dhamma chakka pawaththana Suttta, there are altogether 22 levels of Heavens. The first seven levels are for Davas who are not freed from attachment to sensual worlds (kamaloka). Bhummattha devas.. Cātummahārājika devas....  Tāvatiṃsa,....  Yāma,....  Tusita,..  Nimmānaratī, ....  Paranimmitavasavattī.... are those seven.

The next 15 levels are the adobes of the Brahmas. Brahmas of Brahma Parisajja... Brahma Purohita... Maha Brahma... Parittabha... Appamanabha... Abhassara... Parittasubha... Appamana subha... Subhakinna... Vehapphala... Aviha... Atappa... Sudassa... Sudassi... and Akanittha… reside in them.

The Suddhavasa Brahmaloka or Pure Abodes are a group of five heavens. They are the exclusive Planes of Anagamis or Never-Returners (those who have attained the third stage of Sainthood). Ordinary beings are not born in these states. Those who have attained Anagami in other planes are reborn in these Pure Abodes. Later, they attain Arahanthood and reside in those planes until that life-term ends. The names of the inhabitants of these Pure Abodes are: Aviha, Atappa, Sudassa, Sudassi and Akanittha.

Now I will like to share a short story behind the following Dhammapada:

“Chandajato anakkhate1manasa ca phuto siya
Kamesu ca appatibaddha citto uddhamsoto'ti vuccati”

He who has developed a wish for the Ineffable (Nibbana), he whose mind realises it (with the three Fruits), he whose mind is not bound by material pleasures, such a person is called an 'Upstream-bound One'.

On one occasion the pupil of an elderly monk asked him whether he had attained Arahanthood; but he did not say anything although he had actually attained the third stage of Sainthood. He kept silent because he had resolved not to talk about his attainment until he had attained Arahanthood. But he passed away without attaining Arahanthood, and also without saying anything about his attainment.

His pupils thought that their teacher had passed away without attaining Sainthood and they felt sorry for him. They asked the Buddha where their teacher was reborn. He replied, 'Bhikkhus! Your teacher, who was an Anagami before he passed away, is now reborn in the abodes of the Brahmas (Suddhavasa Brahmaloka). He did not reveal his attainment because he felt ashamed that he had achieved only that much. He was ardently striving to attain Arahanthood. Your teacher is now freed from attachment to the sensual world (kamaloka).

The English translations of these different planes are a bit difficult to comprehend without a proper explanation of each. FYI... Some of them are... ...of the gods that have Gone to Bliss......of the Contented gods...of the gods that Delight in Creating... of the gods that Wield Power over others' Creations... of the gods of Brahma's Retinue... of the Radiant gods... of the gods of Limited Radiance... of the gods of Measureless Radiance... of the gods of Streaming Radiance... of the Glorious gods... of the gods of Limited Glory... of the gods of Measureless Glory... of the gods of Refulgent Glory... of the Very Fruitful gods... of the gods Bathed in their own Prosperity... of the Untormenting gods... of the Fair-to-see gods... of the Fair-seeing gods... of the gods who are Junior to None... of the gods of the base consisting of the infinity of space...of the gods of the base consisting of the infinity of consciousness... of the gods of the base consisting of nothingness...

Comment: Thank you, It is hard to find direct sources in buddhism about minor topics like this.